# iPhone Xcode 4 file bundle problem

Tags: iphone, file, xcode4

I'm developing an app that needs to save files and than show the titles on a tableview and it just works fine on xcode 3, now I have xcode 4 and when I load the tableView with the titles of all the files it crashes because of a bad access. The files are stored in the main bundle. I noticed that if I cut out the content of viewDidLoad (where i load the list of the files) the app works fine! This is the content of my `viewDidLoad`:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

list = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:NULL];
```

Anyone can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to check if the file list is empty.

```
NSError* error;
list = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error];

if (!list)
{
    NSLog(error);
}
```

It might be that due to some SDK update the directory you are accessing is either not accessible or empty. But since your program crashes it indicates your `list` variable is `0x0`.

Comment: I tried to return the list content in my debug window. Indeed, it returns the files in the Dir. It's not a 0x0 list. Even if I try your suggestion nothing changes.

Comment: @Riccardo, what is the content of the NSError object in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, `list` seems to be a ivar. If that is correct then you are assigning an autoreleased value to `list`. If you do access this later, you will be trying to access a deallocated object and hence have an error. If you have an `retain`ed property defined for `list`, then you can do,

```
self.list = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:NULL];
```

If you for some reason, having a property isn't possible then do simply call retain on it like this,

```
list = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:NULL] retain];
```